# Удалить ветку вложенного дерева ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть массив вида

```
"data": [{
      "id": 1221,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2222,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3123,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    },
```

Я выбираю id 1221, 2222 как мне оставить только одну ветку ReactJS?

```
 {
          "id": 3123,
          "name": "Folder3",
          "parentId": 1
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1221,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "parentId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2222,
      "name": "Folder2",
      "parentId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3123,
      "name": "Folder3",
      "parentId": 1
    }
  ]
};

/*
const unwantedId = 3123;

let index = obj.data.findIndex(item => item.id === unwantedId);
obj.data.splice(index, 1);
*/

const unwantedIds = [1221, 2222];
obj.data = obj.data.filter(item => !unwantedIds.includes(item.id))

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: А как это можно сделать на reactjs?

Comment: С реактом дела никогда не имел, но логично предположить, что как-то похоже.

Comment: а что разве react не использует js страный вопрос. в реакте разметка генерится через map к примеру